# How to highlight search words in vim permanently?

Tags: vim

I want to highlight the search keyword in Vim. Mainly I use vim to debug the logs.

I always have to use `:se hlsearch` to highlight the search keyword.

So, I want the solution that it should set command permanently, and I should not use the command always when vim starts.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Set the command in .vimrc.

Use the following commands:

1. Open `~/.vimrc` file (or create it if it didn't exist).
2. Add `set hlsearch` in the file.
3. Save the file.

Now your search will always be highlighted in vim.

For single time use, just use `:set hlsearch` in vim, which will be in effect for that instance only.

Comment: how to remove that highlight once i have found out the matches? i pressed escape and the highlight still exists.

Comment: `nnoremap <CR> :noh<CR>`
then press enter to clear highlighted

Comment: For those who are looking to remove the highlight(s), according to :help hlsearch, just type :nohlsearch. Your next search will still get highlighted.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to highlight multiple searches (in parallel, with different colors), check out my [Mark plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666); it also allows to persist the highlightings across Vim sessions through the *viminfo* file; cp. `:help mark-persistence`.

Answer (score 4):

For those wanting to visually keep highlighted their search:

`:syn match stupid "`<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>`"`

`:hi stupid ctermbg=Red guibg=Red`

Explanation:

The first line add your regex to a syntax type called "stupid" (note that <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> means you must press ctrl+R then / to get the content of the search registry).

The second line gives a red color to the "stupid" syntax regex.

Answer (score 0):

My SelX plugin allows you to highlight and search for many different things at once on a per-tab basis, with different colours. The highlight config can be saved to a vim session

https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5875

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).